# Has this "optimal constrained transport" notion of convergence of measures been named and/or studied?

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, real-analysis, measure-theory, terminology

Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space, and let $\{\mu_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}}$ be a family of Borel probability measures on $X$.

> Fix $L \geq 1$. I will say that *$\mu_n$ converges in optimal $L$-Lipschitz-constrained transport to $\mu_\infty$* if there exists a sequence of locally $L$-Lipschitz functions $f_n \colon X \to X$, with $\,f_n \!\!\overset{\text{unif.}}{\to}\! \mathrm{id}_X\,$ as $n \to \infty$, such that $f_{n\ast}\mu_n \overset{\text{TV}}{\to} \mu_\infty$ as $n \to \infty$.

(Here $_\ast$ denotes the pushforward measure and $\overset{\text{TV}}{\to}$ denotes convergence in total variation norm. A function $f$ is called "locally $L$-Lipschitz" if every point $x$ has a neighbourhood $U$ such that for all $y,z \in U$, $d(f(y),f(z)) \leq Ld(y,z)$.)

Intuitively, the idea is: I need to rearrange as much as possible of the mass of $\mu_n$ in such a way that the result corresponds to as much as possible of the mass of $\mu_\infty$, with as little rearranging motion as possible, but within the constraint that particles of matter that were originally very close together cannot become separated from each other by a factor larger than $L$. The convergence of $\mu_n$ to $\mu$ means that for sufficiently large $n$ I can fulfil this task arbitrarily well.

> Has this notion of convergence of measures been named and/or studied before? Is it known whether this convergence corresponds to a metrisable topology?

**Remark.** This definition is slightly similar in flavour to the definition of the Skorokhod topology for càdlàg functions on a closed interval, except that (i) I do not assume invertibility of the functions $f_n$, and (ii) I have introduced a Lipschitz constraint.

Comment: Sorry, I have just fairly substantially changed the question, as I realise that what I asked about before (though perhaps appearing slightly more "natural") is fairly different from what I was picturing.

Comment: Why is local instead of global Lipschitz important for your definition? Does local Lipschitz with a fixed constant not imply global Lipschitz?

Comment: @Steve Yes, you're probably right that for functions on the whole of $\mathbb{R}^d$ (or a convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$), locally $L$-Lipschitz implies globally $L$-Lipschitz. But I guess I was really picturing more general metric spaces (or, at least, smooth manifolds or not-necessarily-convex subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$.) Since I changed the question from asking about smoothness to asking just about Lipschitz, I will change the "bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$" formulation to just asking about compact metric spaces.

Comment: Okay, I've changed the formulation from $\mathbb{R}^d$ to general metric spaces.